# Trying to fit a generalized mixed effect model for zero inflated semi-continuous data in R

Tags: r, model, continuous

I'm trying to fit a generalized mixed effect model for zero inflated semi-continuous data in R using the `GLMMadaptive` package. I have 13 variables but even just getting 2 of them (like Temperature and Salinity) to run would be great and I can expand from there. hog.cpue is the dependent variable, the rest are predictor. I can't get it to converge. I've tried adding the `iter_EM = 0, max_coef_value = 150` which cleared up the first 2 errors but still cant get it to fully run.

I've tried this code

```
> km1 <- mixed_model(hog.cpue ~ Temperature + Salinity, random = ~ 1 | Reference, data = hogobsA2, 
+                    family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
+                    zi_fixed = ~ hog.cpue, iter_EM = 0, max_coef_value = 150)
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Being the novice that I am, I'm not even sure where columns are defined in this function. 
The full base code for the `hurdle.lognormal()` function of the `GLMMadaptive` package can be found here https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html#two-part-mixed-effects-model-for-semi-continuous-data but most of it is way over my head.

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way to analyze this data that would be awesome! I've tried 9 different ways to get zero inflated models to run and always run into a snag. On the page provided above there are two other methods, but I'm not sure how to tell which is the best for my data. The one I tried is the only one that specified continuous data.

This is my data...

```
structure(list(Reference = c("BBM2009110105", "BBM2012090101", 
"BBM2009080109", "BBM2013070110", "BBM2011080103", "BBM2015100105", 
"BBM2009090104", "BBM2008060208", "BBM2018070702", "BBM2012060104", 
"BBM2016070103", "BBM2010050102", "BBM2014070102", "BBM2010050109", 
"BBM2010050105", "BBM2017110107", "BBM2008110202", "BBM2010090102", 
"BBM2015080108", "BBM2011060103", "BBM2012060106", "BBM2018060103", 
"BBM2018090108", "BBM2009110110", "BBM2014070101", "BBM2010080106", 
"BBM2011090101", "BBM2013050108", "BBM2012090110", "BBM2010050107", 
"BBM2014080406", "BBM2009110106", "BBM2009070109", "BBM2017080103", 
"BBM2013050104", "BBM2017090105", "BBM2009080104", "BBM2016110106", 
"BBM2017100104", "BBM2015060107", "BBM2013100103", "BBM2013080403", 
"BBM2018100105", "BBM2014090102", "BBM2016110108", "BBM2018080401", 
"BBM2013060107", "BBM2015070110", "BBM2016100103", "BBM2013070102"
), NODCCODE = c("6177010102", "6189021300", "6177010102", "6177010100", 
"6177010102", "8762020101", "5509051200", "5509051200", "8839010901", 
"5509051202", "5509051202", "8820020102", "6177010102", "6177010102", 
"6189021300", "6189021300", "6189021300", "6177010102", "6177010102", 
"5509051202", "6177010102", "8839010901", "8747020202", "6189010301", 
"5509051202", "8747010803", "5509051202", "8820023901", "8839010901", 
"6177010102", "6177010100", "6189021300", "5509051200", "6177010100", 
"8820020102", "6189021300", "5509051200", "5509051202", "6189021300", 
"6189010301", "8762020101", "8839010901", "6177010100", "5509051202", 
"6189021300", "8839010901", "5509051202", "5509051202", "6177010100", 
"6177010102"), Depth = c(-1.34375613733192, 0.858911039351898, 
-0.609533745103979, -0.364792947694666, 0.858911039351898, 0.614170241942585, 
-0.120052150285353, -1.46612653603657, 0.247059045828616, -0.364792947694666, 
2.20498542510312, -0.120052150285353, 0.00231824841930331, 0.491799843237929, 
0.491799843237929, 3.30631901344503, 0.736540640647242, -1.34375613733192, 
1.59313343157984, 1.96024462769381, 0.736540640647242, -0.120052150285353, 
0.369429444533272, -1.34375613733192, 0.12468864712396, -0.364792947694666, 
0.858911039351898, 0.369429444533272, -0.364792947694666, -0.854274542513292, 
-0.487163346399323, 0.614170241942585, -0.120052150285353, -0.976644941217948, 
0.614170241942585, 0.736540640647242, -0.609533745103979, 1.10365183676121, 
1.83787422898915, 1.71550383028449, 1.10365183676121, -0.120052150285353, 
0.491799843237929, 0.369429444533272, -0.487163346399323, 1.10365183676121, 
-0.487163346399323, -0.364792947694666, -1.0990153399226, 0.858911039351898
), Temperature = c(-1.8772752877957, -0.109512367327292, 0.738045197280849, 
0.30215844976809, 0.713829266863474, -0.472751323587924, 0.326374380185466, 
0.931772640619853, 1.00442043187198, -0.133728297744667, 1.19814787521098, 
-0.182160158579419, 0.447454032272344, 0.0842150760117116, -0.133728297744667, 
-1.80462749654357, -1.99835493988258, 0.616965545193972, 1.00442043187198, 
0.689613336446098, -0.157944228162043, 0.399022171437593, 1.07706822312411, 
-1.61090005320457, 0.374806241020217, 0.616965545193972, 0.52010182352447, 
0.229510658515965, 0.108431006429087, 0.205294728098589, 0.883340779785102, 
-1.6835478444567, 0.52010182352447, 0.883340779785102, 0.0842150760117116, 
-0.0368645760751657, 0.7864770581156, -0.642262836509552, -1.00550179277018, 
0.544317753941845, -1.41717260986557, 0.495885893107094, 0.132646936846462, 
0.568533684359221, -0.545399114840051, 0.859124849367726, 0.762261127698225, 
1.29501159688048, -0.424319462753173, 0.229510658515965), Conductivity = c(-1.21896005737695, 
-0.631273978174986, 0.503568105801218, -0.104383010614606, 1.45602485485267, 
0.625158329084382, 0.321182770876471, 1.29390455714179, 0.280652696448749, 
-1.25949013180467, 1.43575981763881, -1.01630968523834, 0.442772994159636, 
-1.56346569001258, -1.15816494573537, 0.787278626795268, 1.29390455714179, 
-0.469153680464099, 0.787278626795268, 1.09125418500318, 0.321182770876471, 
0.05773728709628, -0.975779610810618, -1.72558598772347, 0.483303068587356, 
-1.09736983409378, 0.969663961720015, 0.503568105801218, -0.73259916424429, 
-2.15115176921454, 0.503568105801218, 0.604893291870521, 1.45602485485267, 
-2.00929650871752, 0.564363217442799, 0.645423366298243, 0.402242919731914, 
0.321182770876471, 0.929133887292294, 0.280652696448749, 0.463038031373495, 
-1.78638109936505, 0.54409818022894, 0.361712845304192, 0.361712845304192, 
-0.347563457180935, -0.327298419967074, 1.37496470599723, -1.64452583886802, 
-0.813659313099732), pH = c(1.56498992191445, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.0820106753442685, -1.72901127260298, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, 
-0.0820106753442685, -0.905510973973622, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, -0.493760824658945, 
-0.0820106753442685, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, -0.0820106753442685, 
-0.493760824658945, 0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 
0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, 
0.741489623285092, -0.0820106753442685, -0.0820106753442685, 
0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 0.329739473970408, 1.15323977259977, 
1.15323977259977, 0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, -0.905510973973622, 
1.15323977259977, -0.493760824658945, 0.329739473970408, -0.493760824658945, 
0.329739473970408, 0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -1.3172611232883, 
-0.493760824658945, 1.15323977259977, -0.493760824658945, -1.3172611232883, 
0.329739473970408, -0.0820106753442685, -1.3172611232883, -1.3172611232883
), Salinity = c(-1.12894483601917, -0.599890886264641, 0.486061957968336, 
-0.0708369365101144, 1.46063502330562, 0.653131626311871, 0.3189922896248, 
1.29356535496209, 0.263302400176955, -1.18463472546701, 1.40494513385778, 
-0.961875167675634, 0.458217013244413, -1.49092911743016, -1.10109989129525, 
0.848046239379328, 1.34925524440993, -0.460666162645029, 0.76451140520756, 
1.09865074189463, 0.346837234348723, 0.0683877871094981, -0.961875167675634, 
-1.60230889632585, 0.486061957968336, -1.0454100018474, 0.987270962998941, 
0.513906902692258, -0.683425720436409, -2.07567295663253, 0.486061957968336, 
0.653131626311871, 1.46063502330562, -1.93644823301292, 0.597441736864025, 
0.680976571035793, 0.402527123796568, 0.374682179072646, 0.987270962998941, 
0.291147344900878, 0.513906902692258, -1.71368867522154, 0.569596792140103, 
0.374682179072646, 0.402527123796568, -0.349286383749339, -0.293596494301495, 
1.34925524440993, -1.54661900687801, -0.766960554608177), DissolvedO2 = c(2.3781250547958, 
0.102780135236268, -0.124754356719685, -0.57982334063159, -0.124754356719685, 
0.102780135236268, -0.750474209598555, 0.0458965122472799, -0.636706963620578, 
1.18356897202704, -0.466056094653614, 0.159663758225256, -1.77437942340034, 
1.24045259501603, 0.0458965122472799, 0.557849119148173, -0.0678707337306965, 
-0.0109871107417085, 0.102780135236268, -0.466056094653614, 0.0458965122472799, 
-0.181637979708673, 0.330314627192221, 1.80928882490591, -1.4899613084554, 
-0.29540522568665, 0.159663758225256, 1.35421984099401, 0.956034480071091, 
2.66254316974074, 0.728499988115138, 0.444081873170197, 0.387198250181209, 
-0.636706963620578, 0.500965496159185, -2.0019139153563, -0.238521602697661, 
0.557849119148173, 0.159663758225256, -0.0678707337306965, 0.785383611104126, 
-0.466056094653614, -0.978008701554508, -0.864241455576531, 0.614732742137162, 
-1.60372855443338, 2.60565954675175, -0.124754356719685, -0.636706963620578, 
-0.57982334063159), Secchi_depth = c(-1.38143088689724, -0.674407019999457, 
-0.250192699860789, -1.38143088689724, 1.16385503393477, 0.881045487175659, 
0.0326168468983229, -1.09862134013813, 0.456831167036991, -0.250192699860789, 
2.71930754110989, 0.456831167036991, 0.174021620277879, 0.739640713796103, 
0.739640713796103, 3.56773618138722, 1.30525980731433, -1.38143088689724, 
2.01228367421211, 0.0326168468983229, 0.739640713796103, 0.0326168468983229, 
-0.674407019999457, -1.38143088689724, 0.315426393657435, -0.250192699860789, 
1.16385503393477, 0.598235940416547, -1.09862134013813, -0.815811793379013, 
-0.391597473240345, 0.881045487175659, 0.0326168468983229, -0.957216566758569, 
0.881045487175659, 1.02245026055522, -0.250192699860789, 1.87087890083255, 
1.58806935407344, 2.15368844759166, 0.174021620277879, -1.80564520703591, 
-1.09862134013813, -0.533002246619901, -0.391597473240345, 0.174021620277879, 
-0.674407019999457, -0.250192699860789, -1.09862134013813, 0.174021620277879
), Seagrass_habitat_descriptor = c(0.812860286079953, NaN, -1.19050642465534, 
NaN, -0.188823069287694, -2.19218978002299, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, 0.812860286079953, NaN, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, -1.19050642465534, 
NaN, NaN, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, 0.812860286079953, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, -1.19050642465534, 0.812860286079953, 
-0.188823069287694, 0.812860286079953, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, 
-1.19050642465534, 0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, -2.19218978002299, 
0.812860286079953, -0.188823069287694, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, -1.19050642465534, -2.19218978002299, -2.19218978002299, 
NaN, 0.812860286079953, NaN), Distance_to_edge = c(0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, -1.22577651024171, 0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, 
0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, -0.805331105298617, -1.22577651024171, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.22577651024171, NaN, NaN, -1.20475423999455, 
NaN, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, 0.855428244226582, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, -1.22577651024171, 0.855428244226582, 0.855428244226582, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, -1.22577651024171, -1.22577651024171, 
-1.22577651024171, NaN, 0.771339163237964, NaN), BycatchQuantity = c(-0.0418322197301852, 
-0.448703271363022, -0.768387669074537, 1.992523038434, -0.564952143258119, 
-0.332454399467926, -0.21620552757283, 0.830034319483037, -0.50682770731057, 
-0.332454399467926, -0.681201015153215, 0.248789960007556, -0.448703271363022, 
-0.797449887048311, -0.623076579205667, -0.826512105022085, 0.248789960007556, 
0.248789960007556, 0.0744166521649111, 0.830034319483037, -0.623076579205667, 
0.248789960007556, -0.564952143258119, -0.0999566556777333, -0.797449887048311, 
-0.739325451100763, 4.89874483581141, 1.70190085869626, -0.448703271363022, 
-0.623076579205667, -0.332454399467926, -0.198768196788565, 1.41127867895852, 
-0.0418322197301852, 0.132541088112459, -0.21620552757283, -0.21620552757283, 
2.57376739790948, -0.611451692016157, 0.190665524060007, -0.739325451100763, 
-0.21620552757283, -0.0418322197301852, 3.27126062928006, -0.623076579205667, 
-0.332454399467926, 1.992523038434, 1.70190085869626, 1.41127867895852, 
1.70190085869626), Dist_tow = c(1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, -1.59889664136207, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
-1.59889664136207, 0.216133493763229, -0.691381573799419, -0.691381573799419, 
0.216133493763229, -5.22895691161265, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
-3.41392677648736, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, 
0.216133493763229, 1.12364856132588, -0.691381573799419, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, -3.41392677648736, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229, 
0.216133493763229, -0.691381573799419, 0.216133493763229, 0.216133493763229
), Bearing = c(-0.373608799006711, -0.67731447002544, 0.436272990376564, 
0.841213885068202, -1.13287297655353, -1.58843148308162, -0.778549693698349, 
1.86368964416459, -0.778549693698349, 1.14491955608693, -0.869661395003968, 
-1.2847258120629, 1.75233089812439, 0.537508214049473, -1.2847258120629, 
-0.67731447002544, 0.07182618515409, -0.67731447002544, 0.537508214049473, 
-0.373608799006711, 0.233802543030745, 0.294543677234491, 0.132567319357836, 
-0.0699031279879832, 1.75233089812439, -0.373608799006711, 1.44862522710566, 
-1.58843148308162, -0.0699031279879832, 0.638743437722383, 1.44862522710566, 
-1.2847258120629, -0.0699031279879832, 1.79282498759355, -0.67731447002544, 
0.335037766703654, 0.233802543030745, -1.29484933443019, 1.95480134547021, 
0.0313320956849262, -0.373608799006711, -0.67731447002544, -1.13287297655353, 
1.54986045077857, 1.0639313771486, 0.2844201548672, 0.841213885068202, 
0.739978661395292, -1.01139070814604, -1.18349058838999), hog.cpue = c(-0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 1.02183821998587, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
3.63244238455178, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 1.02183821998587, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
1.02183821998587, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
1.02183821998587, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, -0.283463862297085, 
-0.283463862297085)), row.names = c(135L, 320L, 109L, 379L, 242L, 
544L, 114L, 18L, 696L, 293L, 572L, 142L, 441L, 149L, 145L, 676L, 
62L, 181L, 527L, 222L, 295L, 682L, 717L, 140L, 440L, 176L, 250L, 
357L, 329L, 147L, 459L, 136L, 99L, 642L, 353L, 654L, 104L, 615L, 
663L, 506L, 402L, 385L, 724L, 461L, 617L, 704L, 366L, 519L, 602L, 
371L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: where is your id column? you specified it in your model ```random = ~ 1 | id```

Comment: You're using `id` in the formula, but this variable is not included in your data.

Comment: Oh I thought that was some R code snippet or argument that I didn't understand. Thank you. Also is this a standard way to indicate an id or reference column in examples?

Comment: I edited this, but should I just ask it as a new question? I still have problems but they are slightly different. Thanks